# Running profiler on a background agent

Tags: windows-phone-7

My background agent is hitting the 6MB memory limit, and I'd like to understand what objects are being allocated.

In principle I can do this using the Visual Studio Windows Phone Performance Analysis tool, however I don't see how I can run this on a background agent, only on the main app.

Anyone know how to run the Visual Studio Windows Phone Performance Analysis tool on a background agent?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to get the background agent to run while you are profiling you can use ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest [like in this question](http://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2011/11/06/mango-quick-tips-background-agents-debugging/). And [here it is noted](http://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2011/11/06/mango-quick-tips-background-agents-debugging/) that it can still take a while before the agent runs.

If you want to test just the background agent outside of the rest of the app I haven't seen a good way to do it. However I would make a make an empty app and have it manually run the background agent functionality. Then you can profile that and it should work well enough.

Additionally here are some links about keeping your memory consumption down in background agents that you might find helpful:

[Wp7.5 Mango–Background Agents - Chris Sainty (of gReadie fame)](http://csainty.blogspot.com/2011/08/wp75-mangobackground-agents.html)

[Optimizing memory consumption for WP7 Background Agents - Oliver Weichhold](http://weichhold.com/2011/11/16/optimizing-memory-consumption-for-wp7-background-agents/)

Comment: I original tried using LaunchForTest before posting the question, but it didn't work for me - the profiler detaches once you exit the main app to let the background agent run (I can't run both at the same time in my situation).  I also seem to remember it won't work in Release builds, which is what I  need to profile.

Did it work for you?

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. I didn't mean to make it sound like I had tried that. However I still think that making a separate app to run the background agent code should work well enough. To be clear, there would be no actual background agent in this testing app (think of it more like a Unit Test but for profiling) but rather most of the code in your background agent would be run from a button click. You'd have to make a few modifications to the code of course.

Comment: No worries.  I'm assuming that the UI infrastructure will eat up quite a lot of memory if I go with creating a custom app ... it seems strange to impose the 6MB memory constraint on resource intensive background agents as is my case ... makes sense for normal background agents.